# How to use DI-container (Autofac) to register service with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac, mvvm-light

I have the following code snippet on my `ViewModel` and I would like to get rid of the `new` keyword and give the responsibility of creation to a DI-container. However, I am having some difficulties to be able to inject `IDataFileReader` into my `ViewModel` because the given parameter `progress` is tied to a `ViewModel` `ProgressBarValue` property.

Basically, my file reader requires the progress as a parameter so I can display the progress on my UI.

> So the question is, how to register `IDataFileReader` with AutoFac modules on
>   `ViewModelLocator`?

**VieModel.cs**

```
  ProgressBarIsIndetermined = true;
  var progress = new Progress<int>(status => { ProgressBarValue = status; });

  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    IDataFileReader fileImporter = new DataFileReader(progress);
    DataSet = new ObservableCollection<MeasurementPoint>(fileImporter.DataSet);
  });
```

I am using Mvvm Light `viewmodelLocator` and MVVM with WPF. For simple services which do not require any parameters, I can easily achieve this by constructor injection.

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.RegisterModule<AutofacModule>();
  var container = builder.Build();
  ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(container));
}

public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SettingsViewModel>();
```

**AutoFacModule.cs**

The following module is just a draft and would work for a simple constructor injection without parameters.

```
  public class AutofacModule : Module
  {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.RegisterType<DataFileReader>().As<IDataFileReader>();   
      builder.RegisterType<SettingsViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    }
  }
```

Comment: If you're using mvvmlight then have you considered messenger? It has thread affinity but you can dispatcher.invokeasync if you're updating ui.  I don't quite follow why you care about progress if you're using an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: I use the value to display the loaded data count. Mvvm messenger could also be a possible solution. However, in this case, I think one of the proposed approaches could be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative option is to inject a delegate that can create the `IDataFileReader`, rather than an already instantiated one. This will allow you to pass the `Progress` object to it.

Autofac has support for [delegate factories](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html). This could result in something like the following (untested):

```
public class DataFileReader : IDataFileReader
{
  public delegate DataFileReader Factory(Progress progress);

  public Shareholding(Progress progress)
  {
    Progress = progress;
  }
}

public class ViewModel
{
  private readonly DataFileReader.Factory factory;
  public ViewModel(DataFileReader.Factory dataFileReaderFactory)
  {
    factory = dataFileReaderFactory;
  }

  ...
  IDataFileReader fileImporter = factory(progress);
}
```

Comment: With this approach, when is the `DataFileReader` created? I assume it could be easily configured so that the new instance of `DataFileReader` is created every time. Therefore the behavior is identical with the code in my question.

Comment: Yes, every time you call `DataReader.Factory` you are executing the delegate which will create the new DataFileReader.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach. Additionally implemented `private readonly Func<IProgress<int>, IDataFileReader> _factory;` syntax for the `viewModel` to use parameterized Instantiation of my service. Usage: `IDataFileReader reader = _factory(progress);`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do this in nice way :) You should first ask yourself, why does `DataFileReader` cares about progress. Maybe, something else should observe progress and report it to the world?

I'd also recommend avoiding ServiceLocator pattern. Classes should contain only well defined dependencies injected explicitly via constructor. Properties injection should also be considered as anti pattern in my opinion.

Comment: If you have some link to an example solution regarding this progress observing it would be great. I have also read about ServiceLocator being an antipattern, it was just an easy choice because mvvm-light uses it as default.

Comment: I don't have such link, but this is only my suggestion on using Observer pattern. I can imagine `IDataFileReader` reads some data and generates a list. You can add dependency to it called `IProgressObserver` which will expose 2 methods: `Emit(int progress)` and `RegisterObserver(IObserver observer))`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is that `DataFileReader` update the `ProgressBarValue` property of your ViewModel. The easiest way to do that would be to add a `OnUpdate` method on the `DataFileReader`

```
reader.OnUpdate(status => this.ProgressBarValue = status.PercentProgress);
```

By doing so you will add a new responsibility to your `IDataFileReader` interface which may not be suitable and break [*Single Responsibility Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In this case it is common to introduce a new component that will focus on only one thing.

```
public interface IProgressObserver
{
    void OnUpdate(Action<Int32> updater);
    void Update(Int32 percent);
}
```

Your `DataFileReader` can rely on this component and call the `Update` method when needed. Your ViewModel will have a `IProgressObserver` dependency and a `IDataFileReader`

One possible implementation for `IProgressObserver` can be as easy as

```
public class ProgressObserver : IProgressObserver
{
    private Action<Int32> _updater = _ => { };

    public void Update(Int32 percent)
    {
        this._updater(percent);
    }
    public void Register(Action<Int32> updater)
    {
        this._updater = updater;
    }
}
```